# AngularFire2 get list length

Tags: firebase, angularfire2

I have a big list, with many items. I would like to show the amount of items in the list, without pulling the entire list, as I only need the length. Is that possible?

My current setup is:

```
let messages = af.database.list('messages');
// HTML
{{ (messages | async).length }}
```

I think this pulls the entire list, because otherwise how will javascript know what is the length of the array using the `Array.length` prototype, and not a different method?

Comment: Use {{ (messages | async)?.length }}

Comment: That fetches the entire array, which I don’t want to do. I settled in updating a counter whenever something new is added or something is removed, and fetching that counter